# Context menu using C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

I have written C++ code for video display and want to set contextmenu on the video screen as in vlc player occurs. But What happens when I right click on the border of the screen the popup window appears not on the central widget. What is desired that if its clicked anywhere
the popup should be displayed, but it's not happening.

Please help me..

Thanx in advance

Comment: Does popup appeare when you right-click on your widget not on the border of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a video player embedded into a widget (main frame, most probably) and that you bound the right click to the main widget.

If you video player has already a behaviour defined for right click, the event wont be transfer to the parent (the main widget) and thus, the behaviour you describe will appear. Without code or more details, it's hard to give a better feedback, but I'd start looking in that direction.